# ¿Cómo resolver jnativehook java?

Tags: java

estoy ejecutando mi archivo Java y cuando importo estas bibliotecas:

```
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;              
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;       
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;   
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;
```

Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto mi archivo desde la terminal usando el comando `java file.java`, aparece este error:

```
Keylogger.java:5: error: 
packagee org.jnativehook does not exist
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;                      
Keylogger.java:6: error: 
package org.jnativehook does not exist
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
Keylogger.java:7: error: 
package org.jnativehook.keyboard does not exist
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
Keylogger.java:8: error: 
package org.jnativehook.keyboard does not exist
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;                              
4 errors
error: compilation failed
```

**Es decir, estaba diciendo que faltaba la biblioteca, así que descargué la biblioteca a través de Github, pero ¿cómo le digo a mi archivo Java que use esta biblioteca que descargué?**

Comment: Añadiendo la opción -cp a la ejecución: `java -cp /ruta/a/paquetes/usados file.java`

Comment: Su comando me dio el mismo error, mi archivo Java está en `/ root` y mi carpeta jnativehook también está en` / root`, pero jnativehook es un directorio, ¿cómo debo proceder?

Comment: Lo que esté en el classpath debe estar ya compilado. Bajaste los fuentes o un JAR. Busca el JAR de esa librería...

Comment: I have the jar file too, what should I do with it?

Comment: Español, por favor :)  Pon el JAR en un directorio `/root/myclasses` y así puedes hacer `java -cp /root/classes/ file.java`